# JS: Finding next key in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json:

```
{0: "2", 1: "2", $$hashKey: "object:35", undefined: "1"}
```

Currently I am trying to get its key-value with the below code:

```
   var data = JSON.stringify(row);
   var result = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                //display the key and value pair
                console.log(k, v);
       });
```

The above code works fine and I can get my key-value from it.

Now what I am trying to get is the next key-value pairs within the $.each loop.

For example if in the loop the current key is "0" I want to get the next key "1" in the same call itself. If in the loop the current key is "1" I want to get the next key "$$hashKey" along with their values.

Is it possible to do so? I am open to code changes above if required.

Comment: There's no fixed way to define `next` key. You can't control the order of the keys in an object. Look into `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to see if that's of help

Comment: Suggestion: There's no need for jQuery there, you can use javascript's built in `JSON.parse` function. e.g.: `var result = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: It sounds like it does not matter with your code (and that internally it is being coerced to JSON) but what you note as JSON is not technically JSON. That might indicate something is happening internally inside the JavaScript runtime that is changing what you are operating on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding now that the goal is to retrieve keys in the order they appear in JSON, a couple of thoughts:

(1) if you control the source of the object ("row" in the OP code), don't represent it as an object. instead use an array of key-value pairs: `[[0, "2"], [1, "2"], [$$hashKey, "object:35"], [undefined, "1"]]`.

otherwise, (2) roll your own JSON parser that returns an array of key-value pairs for an object.  [This post](http://blog.hiphipjorge.com/writing-my-own-json-parse/) looks to be a sensible start.  Or, you can vastly simplify the task if you are able to make certain assumptions about the values, for example, say you know that all values are strings...

```
// parse a string representing an object, returning an array of key-value pairs.
// assumes values are strings that do not contain commas or colons

function myProbablyNegligentlySimpleJSONParse(string) {
    let trimmed = string.trim().slice(1, -1);
    let components = trimmed.split(',');
    return components.map(kvString => {
        let kv = kvString.split(':');
        return [ kv[0].trim(), kv[1].trim()  ];
    });
}
```

`forEach` passes the current index to the iterator function, so that int can be used to look ahead or behind in the iteration.

```
var data = '{0: "2", 1: "2", $$hashKey: "object:35", undefined: "1"}';
let result = myProbablyNegligentlySimpleJSONParse(data);
result.forEach(function (pair, index) {
    let [k, v] = pair;  // now k and v are your key and value
    console.log(`key is ${k} value is ${v}`)
    if (index < result.length-1) {
        let [nextK, nextV] = result[index+1];
        console.log(`next key is ${nextK} next value is ${nextV}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have my json as above, or can be more key pair values, above is just an example. So first I want to loop though my Json, in my loop when I retrieve my first   key pair value I also want to find out what would my next value be. So if I retrieve my key "0", in the same loop itself I want to find my next key which is "1". All this as per the json that was received in javascript client side. There is no interaction with the server at this moment. Now coming back to your code, I tried using your code, it gives error "pair is not iterable" on line $.each.

Comment: Also FYI with your code the value of let result I get is an Array(3) as:
0:(2) [""0"", ""23ss""], 1:(2) [""$$hashKey"", ""object"], 2:(2) [""undefined"", ""1""]

Comment: @aman - we have our wires crossed on the input based on my refs to the OP.  Edited to show exactly how to run with the input from your question.

Comment: Thanks this works now and I can get the key value pairs. But again as my original post, would it be possible to fetch the next key value within the foreach loop. So if you are on the first key, try to find the next key within that loop.

Comment: @aman - see edit.  forEach passes an index to the iterator as a second parameter.  Be careful when adding or subtracting to it  that the index remains inside the array bounds.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks for all your explanation and inputs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the keys to an array, then run through it with a `forEach` to have access to the keys index. Important to note that objects are unordered, so your key order one time may differ from the next time:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    if (nextIndex === keys.length) return; //out of bounds
    var nextKey = keys[nextIndex];
});
```

Edit: As pointed out by the comments - if you want the keys in the same order each time, call `.sort()` on your `keys` array with your desired sort logic.

Comment: beat me to it by like 4 seconds, well played.

Comment: me too.  my answer would have recommended `Object.keys(obj).sort()`

Comment: @danh - Added that snippet to the answer <3

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Above works fine and I can get the next key. But again as you mentioned being an unordered object would not work in my case as I was looking to get the next key based on how it was in the json. Any other suggestion you may have. May be related to accessing json.

Comment: @aman - Objects are unordered, if you sent `{a:1, b:2}` from the server to the client, there's no guarantee `a` will be the first key. It's browser based

Comment: @tymeJV thanks I got that but there is not interaction of server here, its all client side here. Just to make it little clear, I have a table of columns and rows where the user enter these values. And the json is generated based on what user entered in that table.  And at some point in my code (angular) I want to parse this json and find out the key value pairs. So I believe there is no issue of ordering here (may be I am not clear)

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your object into an iterable and which will return the **next** `[key, value]` pair each time you call `next` on the iterator:

```js
function makeIterable(o) {
  o[Symbol.iterator] = () => {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    var i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        var done = false;
        var value = [keys[i + 1], o[keys[i + 1]]];
        if (i >= (keys.length - 1)) {
          done = true;
        }

        i++;

        return {
          value,
          done
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

var jsonStr = '{ "0": "2", "1": "2", "$$hashKey": "object:35", "undefined": "1" }';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
makeIterable(obj);

var itr = obj[Symbol.iterator]();
while (true) {
  var item = itr.next();
  if (item.done) {
    break;
  }
  console.log(item.value);
}
```